# Mapping greek-mathematical to slanted text greek

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math

I am using a font, namely Source Code Pro, that does not have mathematical Greek letters (eg. U+1D6FC) but does have upright Greek ordinary letters (eg. U+03B1), which I can slant with fontspec's AutoFakeSlant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont[AutoFakeSlant]{SourceCodePro}

\begin{document}
Math mode: $\mathtt{\alpha}$ % nothing displayed, glyph U+1D6FC not found

Text mode: \texttt{\slshape α} % glyph found and slanted
\end{document}
```

The slanted text letters are good enough for my use, but I would like to automate the mapping, so that, when a \alpha appears in math mode and the Source Code Pro is in use, unicode-math and fontspec fallback to the slanted text glyph (I do not want this to occur when an \alpha is encountered and it is not Source Code Pro that is in use).

How can I achieve this — without having to wrap every $\alpha$ in another command ? I know I can use a font for a specific subset of characters only, but presently there is the added difficulty of mapping a unicode point to another.

Comment: You could just do `\let\mathtt\texttt`   but the version of Source Code Pro I have does not have the Greek in the base plane either so I get no alpha in text or math [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqb3y.png) `Missing character: There is no α (U+03B1) in font SourceCodePro:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;slant=0.2;!`

Comment: @ysalmon  Try `texdoc newcm-doc` has a wider range of mono, but Source Code Pro does not have a good range of mono.

Comment: For those who are fine with changing the font, Julia Mono, Deja Vu Sans Mono offer oblique Greek letters (along with NewCM Mono as mentioned above).

Comment: Addendum: Free Mono Oblique (a clone of Courier) has oblique Greek letters as well.